# Centralized catalina properties

Tags: java, tomcat, service, spring-batch, configuration-files

We have a service (java, spring-batch, tomcat) that runs on a number of environments. Each environment has to have its own configuration files, like for example the catalina properties.

Is there a way to have a centralized system, so that the service just knows on which environment it's running and it automatically gets its own properties? Maybe using a db or the active directory?

Or at least an easier way to manage these, without having to manually adjust each and every one?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the Spring Cloud project.  Specifically the Spring Cloud Config project.  It exposes a config server that clients can call into to obtain environment specific configurations.

You can read more about Spring Cloud and the config server here: http://projects.spring.io/spring-cloud/

Comment: Looks like a very interesting option. What we don't like is the fact that the properties are stored on Git. If they were stored in a db it would've been way better. Git is less trackable, there's less security and permissions to push/change them there, it can be down more often than db and so on..

Comment: Suggest it as a feature request (https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-config/issues).  I don't think it's unreasonable.  For the record, they do also support a file system option as well.